# "не" с прилагательным пишется слитно здесь?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, предлоги

> В этом учебном учебном году будет новая программа, **не зависящая** от прошлой.

Должна ли частица **не** быть отдельна от прилагательного в этом случае? Можно ли написать "*независящая* от прошлой" или "*неотличимый* от него"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не зависящая от прошлой - раздельное написание НЕ с причастием при наличии зависимого слова.

Неотличимый от него - раздельное написание НЕ с прилагательным, зависимые слова не влияют на форму написания.

Неотличимый - прилагательное, но не причастие, так ка образовано от глагола совершенного вида (причастия от таких глаголов не образуются).

Comment: Кажется, у Розенталя есть такое правило: при одновременном наличии зависимых и усилительных слов НЕ с причастиями пишется раздельно: совершенно не знающий урока ученик. Тогда: в этом учебном учебном году будет новая программа, [абсолютно/совершенно/в высшей степени] не зависящая от прошлой.

Comment: ДВА ВАРИАНТА У КЛАССИКОВ. "Бунина открыл для себя лишь в сорок лет, по независящим от меня причинам" (Виктор Астафьев). "Он уже собирался произвести последний и самый блистательный вольт, поместив в газете объявление, что меняет шесть комнат в разных районах Москвы на одну пятикомнатную квартиру на Земляном валу, как его деятельность, по не зависящим от него причинам, прекратилась" (М. Булгаков).

Answer (score 1):

Это причастие. И *неотличимый* – тоже причастие.

Отрицание налицо, нужно писать раздельно. "Неотличимый" – слитно, слово "отличимый" вряд ли есть.

В последние годы существует тенденция писать НЕ со многими причастиями, прилагательными и наречиями слитно. Лет 25 назад невозможно было встретить "неслучайно" и "неслучайный". В словаре трудностей русского языка издания 2003 г. указано: только раздельно. Сейчас валят слитно сплошь и рядом.

Answer (score 0):

> *Можно ли написать "**независящая от** прошлой"?*

Можно. См. [**"Русский орфографический словарь"**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9&all=x):

> **независящий***; по независящим от кого-н. обстоятельствам, причинам

Comment: Приведенный источник соответствует академическому словарю Лопатина, где указано, что существуют две формы: независящий/не зависящий от чего-л., причем слитное написание используется при отсутствии зависимых слов.

Comment: Найти сложно, но можно: "Все это были независящие обстоятельства, а не отношения, выяснить которые не терпится" (Андрей Битов).

Comment: Кстати, авторы довольно часто пишут слитно причастие "независящий от" вопреки правилу; здесь, возможно, сказывается влияние прилагательного "независимый от", которое должно писаться слитно.

Comment: Жаль только не добавлено, почему допускаются две формы. Я бы сказала, что значения выражений "независящий от" и "независимый от" в значительной степени сближены, так что правило раздельного написания причастия становится излишне формальным.

Comment: По независящим от кого-л. обстоятельствам, но: по обстоятельствам, не зависящим от кого-л.