# Не( )отличимые друг от друга - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Слитно или раздельно стоит писать *не( )отличимые друг от друга*?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. Написание ***неотличимый*** задается в орфографическом словаре. Также оно считается всегда **прилагательным** (образовано от глагола **совершенного** вида).
2. Раздельное написание прилагательных возможно **в отрицательных конструкциях,** например при усилении отрицания: **ничем не отличимый**.

Примеры:

*Оба они оторопело встали перед Бессоновым, **ничем не отличимые друг от друга**, в толстых и жестяных от снега и инея шинелях; и закостенелые в твердую форму рукавицы их неуверенно ползли к шапкам.*

*О все эти чалмы и бороды — эта униформа головы, одержимой только одной мыслью: рэзать — и потому — а не только из-за запрета, накладываемого исламом на изображение чего бы то ни было живого, — **совершенно неотличимые** друг от друга!*

*Вокзальные ангелы — билетные жучки, **неотличимые друг от друга**, в одинаковых куртках из кожзама, с одинаково ушлым выражением лица — утверждали, что могут отправить нас в любую точку земного шара «без обмана»...*

Answer (score 0):

Споры идут даже о том, [какая это часть речи](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/45033/%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C).

Ну и Справка Грамоты.ру отвечает:

[Вопрос № 213132](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=213132)

> "Даже хочется сотворить такое же нечто, **не отличимое от** крошечных
>   спаленок Пятачка, медовых запасов нехудеющего медвежонка, и воссоздать
>   у себя дома такой же творческий беспорядок, как у Совы".
>
> Как определить, слитно или раздельно следует писать "не отличимое"? Не
>   могу с уверенностью сказать, причастие ли это в значении
>   прилагательного или причастный оборот? Есть ли какие-то "приемы",
>   помогающие определиться — может, какие-то статьи популярные, не из
>   академических учебников, по написанию "не" слитно и раздельно?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> *Неотличимый* является прилагательным, корректно слитное написание в приведенном примере. Это слово следует считать прилагательным потому,
>   что глаголы совершенного вида (к которым относится глагол *отличить*)
>   не образуют причастия настоящего времени.

***Неотличимые друг от друга.***

Comment: Грамота странный аргумент приводит, вроде "уловки 22". А что тогда с не/отличаемыми? Убедительнее было бы с их стороны указать на выражаемую потенциальную возможность или невозможность действия над тем, что выражено существительными, а это является свойством (следствием свойств) - отсюда и "прилагательное".

Comment: Саша, если я только ничего не путаю, всё дело в суффиксе. *Неотличаемый* - причастие, *неотличимый* - прилагательное. См. http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.29 и https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/suffiksy-prichastiy

Comment: Так оно и есть, но это и по значению разные слова (здесь прилагательное на возможность/невозможность действия указывает, а причастие - на факт выполнения действия). Грамота неудачный аргумент придумала, мол потому что не бывает причастий.

Comment: Саш, а может, дело в том, что "неотличаемый" имеет полузаконный статус? Погуглив, я обнаружила его в каких-то сомнительных стихах... 8-(

Comment: Да, трудно представить себе употребление "не/отличаемого" без зависимых слов, ведь по смыслу оно указывает на практику отличения от чего-то (раздельное написание).

Answer (score 0):

У Розенталя есть правило о прилагательных и причастиях на -мый. Они пишутся с "не" отдельно, если имеется в качестве пояснительного слово в т.н. творительном инструментальном падеже (невидимые на небе звезды, но не видимые невооруженным глазом звезды). К слову "неотличимые", на мой взгляд, не может быть в принципе подобрано пояснительное слово в творительном инструментальном падеже (не отличимые кем-то, по-моему, неверно; правильно: не отличаемые кем-то или чем-то). Поэтому "неотличимые друг от друга" должно писаться только слитно