# Слово "отличимый" во всех значениях имеет предлог ОТ?

Tags: лексика, грамматика, морфология

В толковом словаре  есть слово  ***различимый***, но нет слова ***отличимый.***

В Интернете  мне также не удалось найти подходящую информация на эту тему, то есть все возможные значения (если слово многозначное) и  обязательное  падежное управление для него (если такое требуется).

**РАЗЛИЧИМЫЙ**,  Такой, что его можно различить, рассмотреть, расслышать и т.п. <Различимо, нареч. Проговорил еле р.

Собственно говоря, меня интересует, всегда ли  (во всех ли значениях) нужен  **предлог *ОТ*.**  В Нацкорпусе в большинстве случаев используется форма с этим предлогом: ***отличимый ОТ***.

В частности, верно ли предложение: *Вернитесь к табличке удивительных превращений «волка». Легко заметить, что она распадается **на две ясно отличимые части**.* [Л. В. Успенский. Слово о словах (1971)]

Если речь идет о двух частях, то нужно ли использовать выражение «на две ясно отличимые **друг ОТ друга** части» или сделать замену «на две ясно **различимые** части»?

Comment: Странно, даже у Даля его нет. Есть в синонимическом, в орфоэпическом есть "неотличимый", его нет. Вы всегда найдете что-нибудь интересное. +

Comment: Спасибо. Я не то чтобы специально искала   это слово,  а просто  заинтересовалась темой, где обсуждалось написание "не отличимые друг от друга". https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453202/Неотличимые-друг-от-друга-слитно-или-раздельно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово **отличимый**, конечно же, достойно толкования в словарях. Возможно, у составителей просто не было ясности о нём, и, не имея готового источника, они не решились растолковать его заново.

Предлог **от** с этим словом *не всегда* употребляется, поскольку зависимые слова в некоторых случаях могут подразумеваться - например, в значении отличимости "**от всего прочего**", *распознаваемости как такового*. Пример из "Красной книги" (2017 года):

> *На рисунке один из подвидов — астрагал Цингера лиловеющий (A. zingeri var. violascens), легко **отличимый** по сиреневому флагу венчика.*

В материале из Успенского речь идет о табличке со словом "волк" в родственных языках. Основанием для выбора слова из пары "отличимые / различимые" может быть их различающийся смысл: "различимые" имело бы здесь смысл "на фоне целого видны (=*различимы*) две его части" (например, одна часть его таблицы выделена графически); автор же хотел подчеркнуть не столько факт делимости на части, сколько то, что *каждая* часть при этом *отличима **от другой***, - это и есть опускаемая в подобных случаях зависимая часть с предлогом **от** (если её вернуть в форме "отличимые одна от другой части", фраза покажется перегруженной, излишне педантичной). То, что автор *осознанно* выбрал слово, а не просто заменил им похожее, подтверждается тем, что на той же странице (в другом контексте) он употребил глагол "различаются": https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=kEP_AgAAQBAJ&pg=PT49&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=Y2_-RuXejK&sig=ACfU3U2BTT8kTFbB5Ttuwd7OAi7jCxLYeA&w=1280

Comment: Спасибо,  Alex_ander, за ответ, очень вам признательна.  Насколько я понимаю, у слова «отличимый» два основных значения:  1. от  кого-чего. Такой, который можно отличить от другого.  2. Такой, который можно выделить по каким-либо признакам среди других. Надо сказать, что частотность в первом значении (с предлогом ОТ) значительно выше. Значение (2) встретилось мне только  в 5 случаях из 84 примеров, просмотренных в Нацкорпусе.